# undefined columns selected error - works with 1 csv file gives error with more

Tags: r

I have a few functions that I created to to help me analyze some data. My main function starts by binding all .csv files that are in a folder and then calls other functions to perform various tasks, it looks like this:

```
     x <- function (directory){
      files <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
      num_files <-length(files)
      options(stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
      df <- data.frame()
      for (i in 1:num_files) { 
        df_data <- read.csv(files[i])
        df <- rbind(df, df_data) 
        }

      df$Stauts  <- "ba"
      ab_cid <- input() # simple input function see below for input functin code
      df$Status[df$cid %in% bad_cid] <- "ab"
      df$Status <- as.factor(df$Status)
      bad_var_list <- prep_dataset(df)
      df <- df[,!(names(df) % in% bad_var_list)]
      df
      }
```

Here is the input function:

```
input <- function(){
  x <- readline("Enter a comma seperated list of cids with ab status :") 
  x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))

  x

}
```

Another function is later called to clean up the data to meet some requirements that I have

The code in the prep_dataset function starts out like this, it gives me an error in the last line shown here:

```
prep_dataset(data){
     df<- subset(df, Status == 'ab')
     listfactors <- sapply(df2, is.factor) 
     df_factors <- df[,listfactors]

     df_bad <- df_factors[,(colSums(df_factors == "") >= nrow(df_factors) * .20)]
    ......
    }
```

When i run my function `x('Folder Name')` if there is one .csv file in the folder it runs fine, I get the desired results. However if there is more than one file I get this:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df_factors, , (colSums(df_factors ==  : 
  undefined columns selected
Called from: `[.data.frame`(df_factors, , (colSums(df_factors == "") >= nrow(df_factors)*0.2))
```

I took two csv files and manually put them into one and than I compared the data frames that get created when I combined them vs when they are combined in the for loop and they look identical - no clue whats going and why this error message keeps popping up.

Comment: Are you sure that inside your function you need to save the rbind result as df2? I think you should save it as df so you can rbind any additional file to that. If you use df2 you'll always have the last one and you'll ignore the previous ones.

Comment: that is correct - sorry i made some changes to the code and that slipped by me, I in fact do save it as df. Made the changes to reflect that to the original question.

Comment: It seems that you're trying to get all the columns -of type factor- that have missing values (value is "") in more than 20% of the rows when the Status is "ab". Can't seem to have this problem though. can you provide more info on how the datasets look like? do they have the same number of columns and names?

Comment: Could be something very simple like missing a "," somewhere in your function and doesn't allow it to find/specify which columns you want to get. I suggest to clean your environment, remove any unecessary variables and debug your function step by step until you see where exactly the issue occurs.

Comment: Updated the original post with more code - and what you said in your second post about wanting to get factor columns with missing values in more than 20% of rows is correct (that have status ab).

Comment: I think this requires some serious debuging process. If you are sure that the problem occurs within the prep_dataset function then we need to focus on how your datasets look like the moment that function calls it and check what changes happen during those first 4 lines of code inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that for some reason when the read.csv file ran on a folder that has 2 or more csv files it would replace empty `""` columns with `NAs` for what looks like only columns that were all empty, this happened once the `prep_dataset()` function ran this `df<- subset(df, Status == 'ab')`. Also, this would only happen if the folder had multiple csv files and would not happen with a single csv file - I'm not really sure why.

But to fix the issue I had to do get rid of the NAs by doing the following:

```
  char <- sapply(df_factors, as.character)
  char[is.na(char)] <- ""
  df_char <- as.data.frame(char)
```

Now when the function continues and runs

```
  df_bad <- df_char[,(colSums(df_char == "") >= nrow(df_char) * .20)]
```

The `undefined columns selected` error does not happen anymore.